# Mysterious error: "cgo argument has Go pointer to unpinned Go pointer"

Tags: go, cgo, lmdb, unsafe-pointers

I'm getting this error and I don't understand what it means even after reading the [documentation](https://tip.golang.org/src/runtime/cgocall.go). Actually I do thought I understood it, but then it doesn't fit the way it is happening for me. There is also no other information about this specific issue anywhere else on the internet it seems.

For me it happens in [this function](https://github.com/bmatsuo/lmdb-go/blob/a14b5a390eff52e52a20eceb3020038b3d291432/lmdb/cursor.go#L199-L207) (not my library, and it seems to be working fine in many places, so that's even weirder).

In an effort to understand the bug better, I've modified it locally to make each argument to the C function there be constructed separately and see which part triggered the error:

[image]

But turns out the error happens at the line under the cursor, so I think it's just related to the `C.lmdbgo_mdb_cursor_get1()` call entirely.

I thought the error meant that I was passing a Go pointer to a C function and that it could be solved by wrapping the Go pointer with an `unsafe.Pointer()` call, but that can't be as it's already being done and all the arguments to the C function in question are already C types, not Go types.

---

**UPDATE:** With a little more digging I've discovered that the actual `panic()` is being issued at line 689 of `/src/runtime/cgocall.go`:

[image]

So `cgoIsGoPointer()` returns `true` and `isPinned()` returns false.

What do I have to do to "pin" a Go pointer, after all? Or is this question the wrong question?

**UPDATE:** With a little more digging I've discovered that the parameter causing the trouble is `c.txn.key`, which is outside of my control and seems to be set to `new(C.MDB_val)`.

Comment: Given that the linked package hasn't been touched in over 7 years, I wouldn't doubt that it could have done some incorrect things not caught by the compiler at the time. Maybe the `setkey` slice doesn't survive for the duration of the call?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: The source text of the pictures is properly referenced.

Comment: @JimB your guess was worth exploring, so I switched to the https://github.com/PowerDNS/lmdb-go fork of that library, which is has a bunch of users and is being maintained currently. The same problem persists.

Comment: @fiatjaf, then it may be related to how you are calling the library. The next step would be to create a [mre]. Since `p` is the likely Go pointer in question, that would depend on what is passed in `setKey`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, @JimB. The error seems to be triggered by `c.txn.key` (according to log statements I spread all around the cgo runtime files and so on), which is outside of my control. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/PowerDNS/lmdb-go/issues/28 this issue was really being caused by the usage of the Go `new()` constructor to create C pointers that are then passed to C functions. These should have been created with `C.malloc()`.

Apparently this issue had never showed up for anyone else because no one was doing the same mistake I did in my usage of the library: using the same transaction from multiple goroutines, which is explicitly forbidden by LMDB (well, LMDB says threads, but maybe my goroutines were spawning new threads). According to *wojas*:

> This spawning of goroutines may have prevented certain Go compiler optimizations that have previously hidden this allocation bug.